# Custom scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a custom div scroller.  I got it working, but it's still a little rough around the edges. Please take a look..

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5t3Ju/134/)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content {
            margin-top: 100px;
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: solid 1px red;
        }

        #scr {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            border: solid 1px black;
            background-color: #26a0eb;
            z-index: 3;
            opacity: 0;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
        }


        #content:hover #scr {
            opacity: 0.1;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 10);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="scr">
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var strContent = '';
                    for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
                        document.writeln(i + '<br />');
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function () {
            draggable('scr');
        };

        var scr = null;
        function draggable(id) {
            var obj = document.getElementById(id);
            obj.style.position = "absolute";
            obj.onmousedown = function () {
                scr = obj;
            }
        }

        document.onmouseup = function (e) {
            scr = null;
        };

        document.onmousemove = function (e) {
            if (!e) e = window.event;
            var y = (e.pageY) ? e.pageY : e.clientY;

            if (scr == null)
                return;

            var c = document.getElementById('content');

            if ((y >= c.offsetTop + 50) && (y < c.clientHeight + 50)) {
                var pct = (scr.offsetTop - c.offsetTop) / (c.clientHeight - 50);
                c.scrollTop = Math.floor(c.scrollHeight * pct);
                scr.style.top = y - 50 + 'px';
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just focusing on the Javascript:

- I feel a urge to to reference a [story about a monk](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/34?topic=naming). Instead I'll just say that descriptive names will help when you come back to your code or when others try to read it.
  for example:

  ```
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  obj.style.position = "absolute";
  obj.onmousedown = function () {
      scr = obj;
  }
  ```

  Here it would be better to name `obj` something like `draggableElement` or some such. this was I know instantly what we are referring to.
- You are testing `e` and `pageY` and assigning a variable in two different way. Pick one way and be consistent about it. It really matters not what you choose so much as sticking to it.

  Here are a couple of different ways you could do it.

  1. if

     ```
     if (!e) e = window.event;
     var y = e.pageY;
     if(!y) y = e.clientY;
     ```
  2. ternary

     ```
     e = e ? e : window.event;
     var y = e.pageY ? e.pageY : e.clientY;
     ```
  3. or

     ```
     e = e || window.event;
     var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;
     ```

  I personally favour this last way.